# Script is returning my labels only as named "GmailLabel"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I have started building a script for my finances that is dependent on my label names. When I call my list of labels, it returns the correct number of labels, but they aren't named "Discover" or "American Express", they are all named "GmailLabel".. all 10 of them. It's not useful.

I've tried adding and removing labels, which showed that it returns the correct number of labels, just not named their actual names. I've tried calling .getUserLabelByName('GmailLabel') which returns null.

```
function getFinances() {

  Logger.log("Running getFinances()")

  // this prints: GmailLabel 10
  Logger.log(GmailApp.getUserLabels().toString()
             +" "
             + GmailApp.getUserLabels().length)

  // this prints: Found null
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('GmailLabel')
  Logger.log("Found "+label) 

  // this fails to print
  var threads = label.getThreads()
  Logger.log("Found "+threads.length+" threads")

  // this is where my script would append rows with email data
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    var messages = threads[i].getMessages()
    var subject = threads[0].getFirstMessageSubject()
    var body = messages[0].getPlainBody()

    Logger.log("adding row for " + subject)
    if (body) {
      var x = body.match(/\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)
      var money = (x && x[1]) ? x[1].trim() : 'N/A'
    }

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    sheet.appendRow([money, subject])

  } 
}
```

I expect to get labels returned that correspond with my actual label names ("Discover", "American Express", etc.) but instead I only get GmailLabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is printing the class name. You need to call the method to get the actual name.

Replace:

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('GmailLabel')
Logger.log("Found "+label)
```

with:

```
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('GmailLabel')
Logger.log("Found "+label.getName())
```